# Create a scoped object at request level WebAPI .net 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, singleton, .net-4.5

I need to create a singleton object at each request level(like scoped in .net core). 
My scenario is to use the singleton object in multiple threads. I cannot use HttpContext.current as it will become null on new thread and I should not pass HttpContext to another thread as per design.

I have an option to use Unity Container, any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a static variable in that can be shared by all request level?

here is an answer that points out static variables and threads:
[private static variables in c# and thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144842/private-static-variables-in-c-sharp-and-thread-safety)

Comment: I don't want to have it shared at all request level, I need it private to each request at the same time accessible across threads of that request